# Как через библиотеку gson взять 3 элемент?

Tags: java

`// ---
            String input = text;
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            JsonObject mainObject = parser.parse(input).getAsJsonObject();
            JsonArray pItem = mainObject.getAsJsonArray("follows");
            for (JsonElement user : pItem) {
                JsonObject userObject = user.getAsJsonObject();
                JsonArray fol = userObject.getAsJsonArray("user");
                for (JsonElement users : fol){
                    JsonObject userObjects = users.getAsJsonObject();
                    System.out.println(userObjects.get("user"));
                }

            }
            // ---`
   [image]
как мне взять 3 элемент из json ?

Comment: `get(2)`?.......

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случе `user` это `Object`, а не `Array`, таким образом вместо

```
JsonArray fol = userObject.getAsJsonArray("user");
```

и того что дальше, должно быть

```
String displayName = userObject.getAsJsonObject("user").get("display_name").getAsString();
```